# Faster way to select top values and rowmeans

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

Hello I am trying to speed up a block of code that is currently working, but is quite slow with the amount of data that I have. I need to identify the top n% highest value in a row and subsequently use this to make an average by subsetting a dataframe and averaging the values of the subset. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. This is my current approach:

```
corrMat <- matrix(runif(944*9843), nrow=944, ncol = 9843)
GeneExpression <- matrix(runif(11674*9843, min=0, max=100), nrow = 11674, ncol=9843)

cutOff <- apply(corrMat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = quantile, 0.99)
topCells <- corrMat > cutOff


data <- matrix(, nrow = nrow(topCells), ncol = nrow(GeneExpression))
colnames(data) <- rownames(GeneExpression)

  for(i in colnames(data)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(topCells)){
    data[j,i] <- mean(t(GeneExpression[i, topCells[j,]]))
  }
  }

data
```

Comment: Hi Eric. Could you make a small(er) example of your input and what your desired output based on that given input shall look like? Since you are assigning data with two nested `for`-loops there are almost sure better and faster ways to do this.

Comment: This is a little unclear to me, why doesn't `nrow(topCells)` correspond to `nrow(GeneExpression)`? Anyway try `matrixStats::rowQuantiles` for the first part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a smaller version of your example along with my base R solution. Chances are there's also a neat tidyverse way of doing this but I wouldn't know.

```
corrMat <- matrix(runif(24*18), nrow=24)
GeneExpression <- matrix(runif(36*18, min=0, max=100), nrow = 36)

cutOff <- apply(corrMat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = quantile, 0.99)
topCells <- corrMat > cutOff


data <- data2 <- matrix(, nrow = nrow(topCells), ncol = nrow(GeneExpression))
colnames(data) <- rownames(GeneExpression) # rownames are NULL so this is not needed

start <- Sys.time() # benchmarking
for(i in 1:ncol(data)){ # iterate by column rather than colname
  for(j in 1:nrow(topCells)){
    data[j,i] <- mean(t(GeneExpression[i, topCells[j,]]))
  }
}
eric <- Sys.time() - start


start <- Sys.time()
# apply over  rows of topCells to take row means of GeneExpression
# per row of topCells
# then just transpose
data2 <- t(apply(topCells, 1, function(x) rowMeans(GeneExpression[, x, drop = F])))
milan <- Sys.time() - start

all(data == data2)
[1] TRUE

eric
Time difference of 0.08776498 secs
milan
Time difference of 0.02593184 secs
```

Using your original example data, my solution takes 6.43s to run.

Hope this helps.